# Streaming video from WCF server to UWP client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, uwp, streaming

Like what I wrote in the title:
In the server side I have this method:

```
[OperationContract]
Stream GetStream();
```

It return the stream but when I get it in the client, it return the byte[]:

```
 public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<byte[]> GetStreamAsync() {
            return base.Channel.GetStreamAsync();
        }
```

I still dont understand. Do anyone meet this error like me, or how can I streaming with this return type.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do like this?

Add endpoint in WCF Web.config

```
<endpoint address="files" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpStreaming"
      contract="WebService.IFileService" />
<endpoint address="data" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WebService.MyWCFService" />
```

When do like this in your service .svc file

```
namespace WebService
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class MyWCFService : IFileService
    {
        public Stream DownloadFile()
        {
            var filePath = "test.txt";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found");

            return File.OpenRead(filePath);
    }
}

namespace WebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IFileService
    {
        [WebGet]
        Stream DownloadFile(string FileId);
    }
}
```

And on Client side. First update your WCF service reference, and when:

```
public async Task DownloadFile(string FileId)
    {
        string serverAddress = "http...../MyWCFService.svc";

        string filename = "test.txt";

        StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri($"{serverAddress}/files/DownloadFile?FileId={FileId}"), file);

        await download.StartAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see it in my WCF instance :(

Comment: Try to use ```[WebInvoke]``` attribute instead of ```[OperationContract]```. Or you don't see any WCF methods on your client side?

Comment: It auto change my return type in client side :(

Comment: [WebInvoke] I cannot define it

Comment: This function is auto generating by tool. So I do not touch anything in that method

Comment: Are you doing in UWP. I think it due to UWP change something

Comment: Found a webcam streaming [sample](http://technicalstuffhopefullyuseful.blogspot.ru/2012/06/live-c-video-streaming-webcam-server.html), hope this will help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150290/discussion-between-ashchuk-and-bui-quang-huy).